# New Item is array keeps replacing the old one

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am trying to make a list of students with their gpa using an array and a hash. I also uses gets.chomp to make this array user input so a teacher can add to this program. The problem I am having is that every time I add a new student it replaces the old one. What am I doing wrong?

```
loop do
  @students = []
  puts "What is the student's name?"    
  @name = gets.chomp 
  puts "What is the students GPA?"
  @gpa = gets.chomp.to_f 

  def add_students 
    @students << {:name => @name, :gpa => @gpa}      
  end 

  add_students
  puts @students 
end
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed your problem. It's not that each addition replaces the last one... You reset `@students` to an empty array at the top of every iteration of your loop.

So, yes, `@students` will always only have the most recently added student, because your loop creates an empty array, adds a student to it, prints it, then throws it away and creates a new empty array.

This...

```
loop do
@students = []
```

Should be this...

```
@students = []
loop do
```

... so that your `@students` array is created once, outside the loop.